# I have an issue installing Loki on a MacBook pro from 2008

Tags: grub, drivers, live-installation

I Just donwload the elementary iso (the latest), flashed on a Usb with rufus, and try to install on my MacBook pro from 2008. It has a intel 2.4ghz Core 2 duo, GeForce 8600 gt and 4 gb ram. Aparently everything should work.

I have manage to load the grub screen, with a good resolution and working good. I have try all the options. Try, install año OEM and the result os everytime the same: a blank screen.

I think, it may be an issue with the vídeo drivers but i don't know how to fix it.

Thanks you for the support!

Eduardo

Answer (score 1):

Try running in Live USB mode. If that doesn't work try this;

Press e on "Try ElementaryOS without installing"
Go to the bottom of the boot options, and type;

```
outb 0x728 1
outb 0x710 2
outb 0x740 2
outb 0x750 0
i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0
```

then press F10 and it should boot.

Comment: I think this is a larger article on that approach: https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/